# React admin can't fetch from nodeJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-admin

i am deploying to heroku my react/nodejs application.
I'am integrating react-admin, my dataProvider is :

```
const servicesHost = 'http://localhost:5000';
const httpClient = (url, options = {}) => {
const token =  localStorage.getItem('tokenBased')
if (!options.headers) {
    options.headers = new Headers({ Accept: 'application/json' });
}

console.log(token)
options.headers.set('authorization',token.toString());
return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
```

};

Everything is working fine at localhost, the build too, but when i deploy to heroku, react admint won't fetch, the error is :

```
GET http://localhost:5000/api/demande?_end=10&_order=ASC&_sort=id&_start=0 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

i tried to put :

```
const servicesHost = ''; // it return same type of error
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but Heroku won't be able to resolve to a localhost URL. So you need to provide the proper URL instead of localhost:5000 for the deployed version. Localhost only works on your computer because you're hosting the service host on your computer as well under the localhost.

Comment: when we build a react app with nodeJs, we provide the backend proxy for react, so that they can communicate. in my case it doesnt work with react admin